# Getting the currently active page id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

**BACKGROUND**

My app consist of 2 static pages and x number of dynamically generated pages. The number of dynamically generated pages varies from time to time. My first static page is a login page. Once you login you are taken to the 2nd static page which is a welcome screen and then you can start swiping left to view the dynamically generated pages.

**What i want to achieve**

I basically want to get the page id of the currently active page. As in i want to get the id of the page i am currently viewing. i tried the following

```
pageId = $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop("id"); 
console.log('==========================>THIS IS ID: '+pageId);
```

It only gives me the page id of the 2nd static page and not the id of the dynamically generated pages because when i swipe left to view my dyanamically generated pages the console log does not print at all.

Here is the code for the entire relevant js

```
var widgetNames = new Array();
var widgetId = new Array();
//ActivePageId
var pageId = ''

$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $("body > [data-role='panel']").panel().enhanceWithin();

});

$(document).on('pagecreate', '#page1', function () {

    $("#log").on('click', function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "script.login",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                'page': 'create_user',
                    'access': 'user',
                    'username': $("input[name='username']").val(),
                    'password': $("input[name='password']").val()
            },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (html) {
                console.log(html);
                widgetNames = new Array();
                widgetId = new Array();
                var res = html.match(/insertNewChild(.*);/g);
                for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                    var temp = res[i].split(',');
                    if (temp.length >= 3) {
                        widgetNames[i] = (temp[2].replace('");', '')).replace('"', '');
                        widgetId[i] = temp[1].replace("'", "").replace("'", "").replace(/ /g, '');
                    }
                }
                var AllWidgets = ''
                var testwidget = new Array();
                var tempWidgetContent = html.match(/w\d+\.isHidden(.*)\(\) == false\)[\s\S]*?catch\(err\)\{ \}/gm);

                for (var i = 0; i < tempWidgetContent.length; i++) {
                    var widgetContent = tempWidgetContent[i].substring(tempWidgetContent[i].indexOf('{') + 1);

                    testwidget[i] = widgetContent.replace("site +", "");
                }
                var widgetPart = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < widgetNames.length; i++) {
                    var pageHeaderPart = "<div data-role='page' id='" + widgetId[i] + "' data-pageindex='" + i + "' class='dynPageClass'><div data-role='header' data-position='fixed'><a data-iconpos='notext' href='#panel' data-role='button' data-icon='flat-menu'></a><h1>BASKETBALL FANATICO</h1><a data-iconpos='notext' href='#page2' data-role='button' data-icon='home' title='Home'>Home</a></div> <div data-role='content'>";
                    var pageFooterPart = "</div><div data-role='footer' data-position='fixed'><span class='ui-title'><div id='navigator'></div></span></div></div>";
                    var check = "<div data-role='content'><ul data-role='listview'data-insert='true'><li data-role='list-divider' data-theme='b'>" + widgetNames[i] + "</div>";
                    widgetPart[i] = '<DIV style=\" text-align: center; background-color:#989797; font-size: 75pt;\" id=widgetContainer_' + widgetId[i] + '></DIV><SCRIPT>' + 'function UpdateWidgetDiv' + widgetId[i] + '() {' + testwidget[i] + '$(\"#widgetContainer_' + widgetId[i] + '").html(counterValue);' + '}' + 'setInterval(function(){UpdateWidgetDiv' + widgetId[i] + '()},3000)' + '</SCRIPT>';
                    AllWidgets += '<a href="#' + widgetId[i] + '" class="widgetLink" data-theme="b" data-role="button" >' + widgetNames[i] + '</a>';
                    var makePage = $(pageHeaderPart + check + widgetPart[i] + pageFooterPart);

                    makePage.appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
                }
                $('#items').prepend(AllWidgets).trigger('create');

                //Get Active Page ID
     $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
                          pageId = $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop("id"); 
                          alert( "The page id of this page is: " + pageId );
                          });

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Please advise and sorry if it is a bad question to ask as I am a beginner.

Comment: in your code you are getting active page in the ajax call, not when you have swoped to a new page. Put the detection code in a pagecontainershow event: http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show

Comment: Perefect, i have edited the code and now i can swipe to dyanmic pages and the alert  is showing me the id of that page. Now i was just wondering how can i take this pageId variable to update only the page that i am viewing?

Comment: Do a for loop on widgetId comparing each entry to pageId.

Comment: I don't get what you mean there? do i do a loop and set widgetid = pageid ? Also can u post ur earlier answer below with this answer so i will give u voteup. thanks.

Comment: Wherever your update code is running, use the pageid to limit what you update.  Could be via selectors limited to having pageid as a parent, could be something else, it really depends on what your update code looks like...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were getting the active page from within the ajax call, not when swiping to a new page.

The detection code needs to fire when you are on one of the dynamic pages, show you could use `pagecontainershow` to detect the pageID as soon as the page displays (http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show).

```
$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).on( "pagecontainershow", function( event, ui ) {
    pageId = $(":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop("id"); 
});
```

UPDATE: Using pageid when updating pages:

It looks like you want an update every 3 seconds on the active page. so create a function for the entire page:

```
function UpdateActivePage(){
    //get active page
    pageId = $(":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop("id");
    //figure out index
    var idx;
    for (var i=0; i<widgetId.length; i++){
       if (widgetId[i] == pageid){
          idx = i;
          break;
       }
    }

    //run your update
    eval(testwidget[idx]);
    $("#widgetContainer_" + pageid).html(updated stuff);

}

setInterval(UpdateActivePage, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks. also if you could include steps for using the pageId variable to update the current page.

Comment: I had to change things around but this was amazing. i made few changes to make my update more optimized.

Comment: hi @ezanker , i just posted a new question you might be able to help me out as you are good with jquery... its on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508441/updating-table-with-refresh

Comment: i am trying various approaches with 0 luck.