# Updating Table with Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a jquery app which consist of a table. The table has a time field and some number fields. I want to basically increment the values every 3 seconds. So i was thinking of creating a function where i increment the number values and calling it via refresh functions that auto refreshes every 3 seconds.

so basically originally the information is as follows

> Kobe Bryant   10:00   30  4   2
>
> after 3 seconds it should be
>
> Kobe Bryant   10:03   31  5   4

This is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynKed/8/) i have made.

I was not able to do this. I tried to make a function where i increase the table values and call that function as such

> setInterval(updateFunction, 3000);

but no luck. This is how i was thinking of creating a function.

```
var cell = $("#example");
var currentVal = parseInt(cell.text(), 10);
cell.text( currentVal + 1 );
```

Can anyone please provide some advice. I am new to js and jquery and also sorry for poor english if its hard to understand i can clarify what i mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way. Add classes to the cells that need updating:

```
<td>Lebron James</td>
<td class="updateMeTime">08:00</td>
<td class="updateMeInt">27</td>
<td class="updateMeInt">11</td>
<td class="updateMeInt">10</td>
```

In this example, the class updateMeInt means it is a simple integer, and updateMeTime means it is a time value.

Then your update function would iterate through each cell with these classes and increment:

```
function UpdateFunction(){
    $(".updateMeInt").each(function(index){
       var cur = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
       $(this).text(cur + 1);    
    });

    $(".updateMeTime").each(function(index){
        var cur = $(this).text().split(":");    
        var sec = parseInt(cur[1], 10);        
        var min = parseInt(cur[0], 10);

        sec = sec + 3;
        if (sec >= 60){
             sec = 0
             min = min + 1;
        }
        $(this).text(pad(min) + ":" + pad(sec)); 

    });
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ynKed/10/)**

Comment: Hi, this is working fine but i just noticed one thing i have a search bar on top and before i used your code i could search up the ints and the name but for some reason this refresh does not let me search up any int values for example if kobe bryant has 30 pts and i type 30 in search it shows no result. is it possible to search it while the refresh function is being called?

Comment: That is related to the datatables plugin you are using. You should look through its api and see how you are supposed to update cells and keep its filtering working.  You should probably ask another question with that plugin tagged so people familiar with the plugin can help you...

Comment: Yea sounds, good. I think the filter is only working on the initial values i had . i will def take a look at the API. Thanks again.

Comment: hi i just posted a new question is it possible for you to check? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644394/how-to-get-user-input-based-on-radio-button-selection

Answer (score 1):

Try this code on interval function:

```
$("#example > tbody tr").each(function(){
    var s = 0; //--- var for not increase 1st td ---
    $("td",this).each(function(){
        var data = $(this).html();
        if(/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/.test(data)){
          $(this).html(++data);   
        } else {
            if(s == 1) {
              date = new Date();
              var h = date.getHours();
              var m = date.getMinutes();
              if(m < 10) {m = '0'+m;} 
              $(this).html(h+':'+m); 
            };
            s = 1; //--- after 1st td increase ---

      }
   });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynKed/12/)