# How to get user input based on radio button selection?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple program where I give the option to select certain materials. I have one variable declared in my program called cost. So depending on which materials the user selects, the variable should be assigned a different value. For instance.

```
if('#radio-choice-1) is selected{
    var cost = 5;
}
else if('#radio-choice-2') is selected{
    var cost = 10;

 }
```

There are 2 material choices. Both have different $ value for example so say if you pick material A then cost is one value and if you pick material B then cost value is another value.

This is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5CNUM/) I created to make things easier.

Comment: Off-topic: Your code needs refactoring.

Comment: i am quite sure you are correct my code is a mess, as i am brand new to js and html. what exactly do you mean by refactoring? Please explain i knew it was looking like a mess .Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring. I would suggest posting a question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com after solving the current issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your html you have:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1">
    <label for="radio-choice-1">SS316L</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2">
    <label for="radio-choice-2">HDPE</label>
</fieldset>
```

you could put the cost in the `value` attribute like this:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="5.00">
    <label for="radio-choice-1">SS316L</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="8.25">
    <label for="radio-choice-2">HDPE</label>
</fieldset>
```

and use jquery to grab the cost of the selected item like this:

```
var cost = $('input[name=radio-choice]:checked').val();
```

here's a working example of this technique:  http://jsfiddle.net/RhnvU/

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use a combination of `is()` and `:checked` to do this. Something like this should work for you:

```
if($('#radio-choice-2').is(':checked')) { 
    var cost = 10;
}
else {
    var cost = 5;
}
```

Now, this assumes you only have two options for `cost`, 5 and 10.